# Simple function animation

Tags: r, animation

I want to generate a short and easy animation to illustrate how the function x^a changes for x between 0 and 1 and a increasing from 0 to 1. I run this code:

```
p1 <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
alpha <- seq(0, 1, 0.05)
n <- length(alpha)

for (i in 1:n) {
  p2 <- p1^(alpha[i])
  p <- plot(p1, p2, ylim = c(0,1.1))
}
```

The problem is that R waits til the whole loop is done and then just displays all plots, so I have to skip through the plots by myself. What I rather want is that the newest plot replaces the old one and by this getting an animation. I tried using `print()`somehow, but it did not work. Is there any way to do an animation that way?

I know that there are animation packages, but they all seem more complicated than my way. However, if you think it would be better to use one of these, please tell.

Comment: I'm not very sure although I think you may have to manipulate the active device somehow to clear it and then add a new plot? Maybe `dev.new` and `dev.off` somewhere? Hopefully a graphics expert helps you

Comment: How about adding `Sys.sleep(0.1)` after the plot command?

Comment: have a look at gganimate, or google "r plot animation"!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
The adding of `Sys.sleep()` did exactly what I wanted to achieve.